# Is it safe to assume that the CSS :last-child selector will work on all mobile browsers?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given the fact that most mobile browsers are pretty modern, can we assume that :last-child will pretty much work in any mobile browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to CanIUse: http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child

It will work in iOS Safari, Opera Mini, Opera Mobile, and the base Android Browser. I would guess it also works in mobile Firefox as well given it uses pretty much the same base as the desktop version.